# Ping Exception on invalid IP Address

Tags: c#

I receive an error when running a network ping.

As an input, I am giving a range of IPAddress as StartIp=10.1.1.1 and EndIp = 10.1.1.10. If I provide a valid IPAddress as(eg.10.1.1.8) the exception is not throwing, but if any other ip in that ranges ping the exception is throwing why?

I am expecting If it pings other than valid Ip it should not throw an exception.

```
    protected async Task<PingReply?> DoPingAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, uint timeoutMilliSeconds)

    {
        PingReply? pingReply = null;
             
        try
        {
            if (IsTraceEnabled)
                logger.LogTrace($"DoPingAsync() -> [{ipAddress}] Checking reachability.... ");

            using var ping = new Ping();

            pingReply = await ping
                .SendPingAsync(ipAddress, (int)timeoutMilliSeconds)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (IsTraceEnabled)
                logger.LogTrace( $"DoPingAsync() -> [{ipAddress}] Ping status: {pingReply.Status}");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.LogError(exception, "DoPingAsync -> Ping failed!");
        }
       
        return pingReply;
    }
```

`Error||SyskeySoftlabs.AssetManager.ApiService.Services.AssetDiscoveryManager|DoPingAsync -> Ping failed! System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (87): The parameter is incorrect. at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetStatusFromCode(Int32 statusCode) at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.DoSendPingCore(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeout, PingOptions options, Boolean isAsync) at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsyncInternal(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsyncInternal(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options) at SyskeySoftlabs.AssetManager.ApiService.Services.AssetScanAndDiscoveryBase.DoPingAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, UInt32 timeoutMilliSeconds) in C:\Dev\AssetManager\Service\api-service\ApiService\Services\AssetScanAndDiscoveryBase.cs:line 57`

Comment: It obviously needs a valid IP to be able to try and ping it? Why not just catch the error and handle it how ever you want?

Comment: What is the exact IP address that throws this exception. You should have that in your log assuming tracing is enabled. If you ping that same IP from the server from the command prompt, what is the result?

Comment: Is the address that is failing the same IP address as the machine you are using? Ping does not give an exception when an IP is not found.  The exception is occurring at the network card and not due to a timeout which you would normally get when an IP is not found.